# After logging out of SSH, screen sessions disappear on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, ssh

On Arch Linux (I'm on a single dedicated server, where my domain name points to only one IP), when I SSH into a user (say, for example, user mc), and then do

```
screen -S test
```

(or -dmS, the resulting issue is the same), run a command, and then detach from it, then exit out of my SSH session, and log back in, the screen session disappears.

```
screen -ls
```

returns

> No Sockets found in /run/screens/S-mc.

The only way I can reattach to my sessions is if I never logged out of my SSH.

How do I fix this?

- I do have read/write access in /run/screens/S-mc
- I detach from screen sessions with Ctrl-A,D
- `disown -a && exit` gives me the same problem
- `shopt huponexit` returns "huponexit off"

There is no ~/.logout, and ~/.bash_logout is empty, with 3 lines of comments, telling me it's the ~/.bash_logout file

```
ls -l /usr/bin | grep screen
```

returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Oct 31 2012 screen -> screen-4.0.3 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 363672 Oct 31 2012 screen-4.0.3
```

Comment: @Hennes ls -l /run/ tells me that I can't write to /run/, but I can write to /run/screens/S-mc

Comment: @Hennes I can run screen by itself, and I can attach to screen with both -x and -r. After I exit out of my SSH session and relogin, the sockets disappear.

Comment: Just found a similar thing on the Ubuntu site see answer on byobu (also available for arch via pacman) http://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Comment: @NeilNeyman I read it. I installed tmux and gave it a shot: I ran "tmux" and all it did was echo "1;2c", and do nothing else. "tmux list-sessions" returned "failed to connect to server"

Comment: Oh I hit enter to early on that. Was referring to byobu answer

Comment: @Hennes I'm not exactly sure, `ps -ef | grep -i screen` returned `mc 13350 13262  0 21:30 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i screen`, but `kill -CHLD 13356` returned `-bash: kill: (13350) - No such process` while `kill -CHLD 13262` did nothing. Also, when I do repeated `ps -ef...`s, the first number gradually goes up.

Comment: @NeilNeyman well you see, I really want to use screen, as I'm familiar with it. I'll use a different software if screen won't work, but for now, I want to see if I can get screen working.

Comment: Technically byobu is just enhancements for screen but I get your point

Comment: @Hennes I also cd'd into /run/ and did >utmp, I'll restart and try to see if it fixes it.

Comment: @Hennes IT'S A CHRISTMAS MIRACLE! After doing >utmp and restarting, it fixed it all. Thanks!

Comment: Yay. Please post your own answer on this. If you do that, wait a while and accept it then you get some reputation on this site and you will be able to join one of the chat rooms, thus avoiding these long comment exchanges. Ofc. you could also answer some of the other people questions to get that reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my /run/utmp file was corrupt.
To fix my issue, I did

```
cd /run/
>utmp
reboot
```

and it started working again.

Comment: is utmp a command?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but i just find the disappear screen process is run on root. just switch to root `sudo su`, then I can find screen process by `screen -ls`