# screen session is gone after rebooting pc but app still running

Tags: ssh, display

so im hosting a discord bot using a ubuntu ssh server and im hosting it using screen, but when i reboot my laptop while the bot is running the bot is still active but the screen session is nowhere to be seen when i do things like `screen -ls`, when i do `screen -r` it also can't find it back. i searched a lot about it and this problem didn't seem to be so common but i did find this [After logging out of SSH, screen sessions disappear on Arch Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/665528/after-logging-out-of-ssh-screen-sessions-disappear-on-arch-linux) i followed the commands but i did it in `sudo su` because of permissions.
im running on manjaro linux.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, so I wasn't able to find back the screen session after rebooting the pc, I was trying to resume the session or terminate it but I can't because for some reason my pc can't find it. but the bot was still running

Comment: update: for some reason the bot now went off, maybe because it's been on for too long without any login or packets to keep it alive but I'm not sure, after I reboot the system it stays active for at least 30 minutes or longer I'm not sure when It exactly went offline